# Creating XML in python

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7

I was building an XML file using python, which I achieved using the `etree` module.

The problem is that I have to hard code every information, like I have to specify the tag name and its value in the code. What I want is to be able to just provide the tag and value and the corresponding xml is generated itself.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Try reading XSLT, it may help you to create a custom xml on the fly.

Comment: Try to use any template engine like jinja2 or anything like that.

Comment: Show us your code. What have you tried? Where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Building you XML with hard-coded (so static) nodes and values is quite simple. As you said, you should use the `xml.etree` model and manually build you XML. I post you a simple example.

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment

from xml.etree import ElementTree
from xml.dom import minidom

def prettify(elem):
    """Return a pretty-printed XML string for the Element.
    """
    rough_string = ElementTree.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
    reparsed     = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
    return reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="  ")

#declaring tags 
first_level_element = Element('top')
child_element       = SubElement(first_level_element, 'second')

#adding content to tags
child_element.text  = "This is my static tag content!"

print prettify(first_level_element)
```

Comment: HI. Thanks for the input. But I have already achieved this.

Comment: Ok. So I have not understood you problem. Could you post something to clarify the question?

Comment: I do not want hard coded or static nodes. I want them as sort of variables

Comment: You could construct some APIs to dynamically add nodes to your xml structure. Anywary, somehow you have to instantiate your nodes with their values.